# Cant get sql data into listview from a different foreign table (2 tables)

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, listview, webforms

Been stuck on the same problem for days and i have been searching around the web for an answer.

**My question is**: In the code below i got two tables that has 1 foreignkey. I want to display the nvarchar in that table not the ID.

In my aspx page i got a Listview.

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView_Fruit" ItemType="DifferentFruit.Model.Fruit" 
    SelectMethod="ListView_GetData" DataKeyNames="FruitID" runat="server" 
    DeleteMethod="ListView_Del" 
    UpdateMethod="ListView_Update" >
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>FruitID</th>
                <th>Fruit Name</th>
                <th>TypeOfFruitID</th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td><%# Item.FruitID  %></td>
            <td><%# Item.FruitName  %></td>
            <td><%# Item.TypeOfFruitID %></td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
```

Database

```
Fruits 
FruitID(int) Pk
FruitName nvarchar(20)
FruitsTypeID(int) 

FruitsType 
FruitsTypeID(int) (fk)
FruitType(nvarchar(20)
```

Now i display every fruit from a stored procedure.

```
Getting all data.
    SELECT FruitID, FruitName, TypeOfFruitID
    FROM Fruits
Getting all data from FruitsType
    SELECT FruitsTypeID, FruitType FROM FruitsType
    WHERE FruitsTypeID = CAST(FruitsTypeID as nvarchar(20))
```

How can i display the data from the FruitsType? Now it only display the FruitsTypeID not the other row in the FruitsType. I want to display FruitType

My fruit Databaselayer

```
    public IEnumerable<Fruits> GettingAllFruits(int startRow, int maxRow, out int totalRows)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = Create())
        {

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("appSchema.app_getFruits", conn);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@PageIndex", startRow / maxRow + 1);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@PageSize", maxRow);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@RecordCount", ParameterDirection.Output)

                conn.Open();

                using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {

                    int fruitID = reader.GetOrdinal("FruitID");
                    int fruitName = reader.GetOrdinal("FruitName");
                    int fruitType = reader.GetOrdinal("TypeOfFruitID");

                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        Fruits fruit = new Fruits();
                        fruit.fruitID = reader.GetInt32(fruitID);
                        fruit.fruitName = reader.GetString(fruitName);
                        fruit.typeOfFruitID = reader.GetInt32(fruitType);
                        fruitslist.Add(fruits);
                    }
                }

                totalRows = (int)cmd.Parameters["@RecordCount"].Value;

                fruitlist.TrimExcess();

                return fruitlist;
            }
        }
    }
```

My stored Procedure (Updated)

```
BEGIN SELECT ROW_NUMBER() 
OVER ( ORDER BY 
[FruitID] DESC 
)AS RowNumber 
,[FruitID] 
,[FruitName] 
,[FruitsTypeID] 
INTO #FruitsRes 
FROM [Fruits] 
INNER JOIN FruitsType ON Fruits.TypeOfFruitID = FruitsType.FruitsTypeID 
WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN(@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1 AND(((@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1) + @PageSize) - 1 
DROP TABLE #Results 
END
```

The stored procedure is fine but when the stored procedure is called back to the application i getting a convertion error. That says cannot convert from 'Apple' To int.
Error here -->

```
int fruitType = reader.GetOrdinal("TypeOfFruitID");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are basically looking for an [Inner Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208854(v=office.12).aspx), Try this:-

```
SELECT FruitID, FruitName, FruitType
FROM Fruits INNER JOIN FruitsType
ON Fruits.TypeOfFruitID = FruitsType.FruitsTypeID
```

Comment: Thanks @Rahul Singh But something seems to be wrong. I also got a Pager. Like this.

`BEGIN
      
      SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER
      (
            ORDER BY [FruitID] DESC
      )AS RowNumber
      ,[FruitID]
      ,[FruitName]
      ,[FruitsTypeID]
     INTO #FruitsRes
      FROM [Fruits] 
      JOIN FruitsType
ON Fruits.TypeOfFruitID = FruitsType.FruitsTypeID
     

      

      
      WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN(@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1 AND(((@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1) + @PageSize) - 1
     
      DROP TABLE #Results
END``

Comment: Pager as in? This is straight forward sql query for your SP, Rest should be same.

Comment: My SP is saying cannot convert to int.

Comment: @Chrisreed - Where exactly in the SP? Its really tough to answer without reviewing the code.

Comment: @Chrisreed - Why you are checking for `TypeOfFruitID`? There is no such column in your tables right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73495/discussion-between-chris-reed-and-rahul-singh).

Comment: I want to display all Rows. FruitID, FruitName, FruitTypeID but where The fruittypeid i want The nvarchar to be displayed but im getting convertion problem. Just because of The inner join

Comment: Do you understand my problem @RahulSingh

Comment: @Chrisreed - Nope and I am not able to replicate the same as I have limited access to SSMS at work place. Give me some time I will give get back to you once I will be able to replicate the same.